# Como llamo un archivo json desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

como llamo a un archivo json desde javascript ? Es igual que con url o distinto? Por ejemplo un archivo html llama el script abajo y el script llama a una api :
Javascript de ejemplo :

```
Axios.post('http://192.168.0.69:80/ejemplo/ejemplo',datosJSON)
.then((response)=>{
}(error)=>{
console.log(error);
});
```

Html de ejemplo:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Gracias espero que se pueda hacer y se entienda mi idea

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es solo importar un archivo JSON local en otro archivo JavaScript, ¿por qué no transformar tu archivo `.json` a uno `.js` y hacer un `export default`? Después desde tu archivo JavaScript lo consumes con un `import`. Eso es lo que se recomienda en la respuesta a esta pregunta [How to import a JSON file in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944099/how-to-import-a-json-file-in-ecmascript-6), y hacer eso me parece mucho más práctico que consumirlo como si fuera un JSON que viene de un servidor remoto.

Answer (score 0):

Si, es lo mismo, por lo regular las API Rest retornan un json para manejar los datos. Solo que noto que estas utilizando post en lugar de get.

Te comparto un par de ejemplos con la API de Rick and morty

```js
//Ejemplo con fetch

fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then( data => console.log(data.results) )
            
//Ejemplo con axios
axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character`)
       .then(response => console.log(response.data.results))
```

Comment: hola @jacxdev eso hago con algunas api pero si quiero llamar un archivo json por ejemplo /archivo/json.json como lo llamaria desde javascript?